# intento simular el comando tail y head con python en windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

estoy intentando crear un software que simule ser la terminal de linux (bash)

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import os

def clear():
    subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","/c","cls"])

def ls():
    dirlist = os.listdir('.')
    for file in dirlist:
        print(file)

def mkdir():
    try:
        os.mkdir(cmd[6:])
    except Exception as e: 
        print("ese directorio ya existe") 

def cd(cdir):
    try:
        os.chdir(cdir)
    except Exception as e:
        print("el sistema no puede encontrar la ruta")
def rm(delfd):
    try:
        os.remove(cmd[2:])
    except Exception as e:
        print("no se ha encontrado la carpeta o directorio{}".format(delfd))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wt = True
    while wt:
        cmd = str(raw_input("{}>".format(os.getcwd())))
        if cmd == "help":
            print('''de momento no pondré este comando porque el output eslargo y hace dificil leer el codigo''')
        elif cmd == "clear":
            clear()
        elif cmd [:2] == "ls" and cmd[2:] == "":
            ls()
        elif cmd[:6] == "mkdir ":
            mkdir()
        elif cmd[:2] == "cd":
            cd(cmd[3:])
        elif cmd[:2] == "rm":
            rm(cmd[2:])
        elif cmd[:4] == "echo":
            print(cmd[5:])
        elif cmd[:5] == "touch":
            open(cmd[5:], "w")
        elif cmd[:3] == "pwd":
            print(os.getcwd())
```

¿como puedo implementar los comandos head y tail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas son las dos funciones que tienes que implementar en tu código. Obviamente tienes que agregar el llamado a las funciones desde tu código principal y enviarle el nombre del archivo. Se incluye la captura de errores por si el archivo no existe o no se puede leer. Se usó el modulo `itertools` para mayor eficiencia con archivos grandes

```
import itertools

def head(textfile):
    try:
        with open(textfile) as data:
            text_iterator = itertools.islice(data, 0, 10)
            for element in text_iterator:
                print(element, end = '')
    except:
        print("[ERROR] El archivo no existe o no puede ser abierto")

def tail(textfile):
    try:
        with open(textfile) as data:
            all_lines = itertools.islice(data, 0, None)
            num_lines = sum(1 for _ in all_lines)
            data.seek(0)
            line_begin = 0 if (num_lines < 10) else num_lines - 10
            text_iterator = itertools.islice(data, line_begin, None)
            for element in text_iterator:
                print(element, end = '')
    except:
        print("[ERROR] El archivo no existe o no puede ser abierto")
```

Answer (score 1):

Si entendemos por `head`, el mostrar las primeras 10 líneas de un archivo y `tail` las últimas 10. Puedes implementarlo de esta forma:

```
import os

def tail(filename, count=10, offset=1024):
    """
    A more efficent way of getting the last few lines of a file.
    Depending on the length of your lines, you will want to modify offset
    to get better performance.
    """
    f_size = os.stat(filename).st_size
    if f_size == 0:
        return []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        if f_size <= offset:
            offset = int(f_size / 2)
        while True:
            seek_to = min(f_size - offset, 0)
            f.seek(seek_to)
            lines = f.readlines()
            # Empty file
            if seek_to <= 0 and len(lines) == 0:
                return ""
            # count is larger than lines in file
            if seek_to == 0 and len(lines) < count:
                return "".join(lines)
            # Standard case
            if len(lines) >= (count + 1):
                return "".join(lines[count * -1:])

def head(filename, count=10):
    """
    This one is fairly trivial to implement but it is here for completeness.
    """
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = [f.readline() for line in xrange(1, count+1)]
        return "".join([l for l in filter(len, lines)])
```

Ligeramente adaptado de [este código](http://drewfradette.ca/python-native-head-and-tail-functions/), lo que tiene de interesante, es que el `tail` muchas veces se plantea como la lectura completa del archivo para mostrar solo las últimas líneas, lo cual es muy poco performante con archivos realmente grandes, en este caso no se hace esto, sino leer en un buffer los últimos bytes y recuperar las líneas desde dicho buffer.

Para ejecutarlo, algo como esto:

```
print head(file)
print tail(file)
```